# What is the difference between lifecycle methods (in Activities) and the finite state machine (in say the MediaPlayer class)?

Tags: java, android, computer-science

I have come across two concepts in my learning: Life Cycle Methods (as in [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) and [Android Activities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ActivityLifecycle)) and the Finite State Machine as in [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) class of Android.Both concept sound similar to me but I never hear them interchanged in either of the two use cases. Are they similar concepts? If not how do they differ?

PS: I don't have a CS background, just in case they are a basic CS concept.

Comment: Life Cycle Methods are usually just callbacks or hook methods that occur based on an event, there is no enforcement of any sort of design pattern and these hooks don't mean the internal state of the class they call necessarily changes.  A finite state machine is a behavioral design pattern where behavior changes based on internal state and is predictable based on internal state.  For instance you can call `MediaPlayer::play` anytime, but unless ts internal state is in a "prepared" or "paused" state in wont transition to playing.